# Where do files reside while in the trash bin on macOS from an external drive?

Tags: hard-drive, external-disk, trash

I am using a Western Digital easystore drive which is formatted as exFat on macOS Monterey. I deleted about 600GB of files from the easystore drive which seemed to work fine. However, when I right-clicked in Finder in that drive, AND when I go to Disk Utility AND when I check in Apple -> About This Mac -> Storage tab, they ALL say that there is only ~376GB of free space. So in other words, the free space was never actually updated for this external drive to reflect me deleting the 600GB of files. Upon further investigation, I saw that the files were actually in the Trash bin still, and when I Emptied the trash, they actually deleted for real and now I see that the free space is correctly represented at approximately 900GB of free space as I expected.

This is strange behavior to me (who has spent a lot of time on Linux and Windows) because I dont understand exactly what happens with these files when they are not visible on the drive, but in the "Trash bin"? What if I unplug the drive? Where are the files actually at?

Comment: In the Trash on the external drive.  Each volume has one.  How else would you expect it to work?

Comment: @MarcWilson On other systems I use, there is no concept of "trash" for external drives. Delete just deletes it permanently. Thats how I would expect it to work.